# What are best practices to insert data to two tables at same time with related data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

What are best practices to insert data to two tables at same time with related data in mysql?
Using transaction is the first thing that came into my mind? but any other best practices exist?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, without seeing any other information, the insert(s) should be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Thank you very much